# Data cleaning & subsetting in nested list

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply, purrr

I couldn't find any previous questions which addresses these steps in a nested list. My own attems hasn't got me anywhere either!

I have a nested list `df`.

1. I would like to change the column names of the 3 first columns in
   all data.frames to `c("one","two","three")`.
2. In each data frame want to keep the 3 first columns and the columns
   with the same name as the data frame name in the list.
3. Now each data frame has 4 columns. In each data frame I want to keep the values in the second columns if the values of the fourth column is bigger than 3.
4. Return a nested list, with the name of each data frame and selected
   values from the second column (in step 4).

`Purrr` and `dplyr` approach are preferred but everything else is much appreciated!

```
> dput(map_depth(df,1, head))
list(`CD8_C01-LEF1` = structure(list(...1 = c("1236", "6194", 
"51176", "6402", "6137", "1937"), ...2 = c("CCR7", "RPS6", "LEF1", 
"SELL", "RPL13", "EEF1G"), ...3 = c(448.275813024615, 114.565282822255, 
405.993571415472, 352.462886197845, 152.430598462657, 73.5226212775651
), `P-value*` = c(0, 2.35914832807463e-150, 0, 0, 1.03146807397557e-195, 
3.00681346250943e-98), `CD8_C01-LEF1` = c(6.3388353508401, 1.36075129906401, 
5.11667843995657, 5.22902495053118, 1.35703181746742, 1.72815687302818
), `CD8_C02-GPR183` = c(2.71993044636725, 0.755445092850178, 
2.26029822474036, 3.57732840656951, 0.757664532314421, 0.732003573596204
), `CD8_C03-CX3CR1` = c(-2.50016459757821, 0.0430813598361915, 
-1.47763877045973, -1.31104077043168, -0.118054173396857, -0.217984797372657
), `CD8_C04-GZMK` = c(-0.639352384551204, -0.304854019068466, 
-1.400271288872, -1.56965980479594, -0.128422617265835, -0.701864111617954
), `CD8_C05-CD6` = c(-2.35873754058284, -0.115888861319928, -2.08628173736428, 
-3.32630706764402, -0.177640817498698, -0.215754243123614), `CD8_C06-CD160` = c(-2.85558322130952, 
-0.29530343951866, -2.20232116143474, -3.274807762691, -0.440783845861116, 
-0.56207661416919), `CD8_C07-LAYN` = c(-2.75671138163062, -0.887003245107014, 
-2.40845402752497, -3.47698326675668, -1.03656381624963, -1.46468960616135
), `CD8_C08-SLC4A10` = c(-2.68199272253543, 0.0292368512820967, 
-2.1581654239029, -2.99895134853712, 0.0615744908900675, 0.192173783941343
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), `CD8_C02-GPR183` = structure(list(
    ...1 = c("3575", "4050", "1901", "6653", "1880", "10628"), 
    ...2 = c("IL7R", "LTB", "S1PR1", "SORL1", "GPR183", "TXNIP"
    ), ...3 = c(268.347035159053, 151.397715576146, 423.815475272167, 
    154.131971403975, 161.502687932662, 138.188069200824), `P-value*` = c(0, 
    1.63481853000449e-194, 0, 1.09616441981898e-197, 3.47999420200636e-206, 
    5.87606326954945e-179), `CD8_C01-LEF1` = c(2.25872137515665, 
    1.06433926285014, 2.06890434595653, 1.77222927526522, -2.32256398023726, 
    1.17445992511194), `CD8_C02-GPR183` = c(3.58534594694992, 
    2.33774626980998, 3.1044712936119, 3.00075778716827, 1.54874669286004, 
    2.11053414857411), `CD8_C03-CX3CR1` = c(-2.73122665345433, 
    -3.23251051546321, 2.76359001828421, 0.899851788567591, -3.4595583469893, 
    1.9924219816788), `CD8_C04-GZMK` = c(-1.20359289904198, -2.27859013855459, 
    -0.289843306560729, 0.0930099548084882, 0.293766916539111, 
    -1.05998934689132), `CD8_C05-CD6` = c(0.771026257612103, 
    -1.84446654315228, -1.92859019625536, -0.993527571866541, 
    -0.517242518264243, -1.05505195656161), `CD8_C06-CD160` = c(-1.26433565787961, 
    -3.62072638085859, -1.99838091859197, -2.66224984657089, 
    -3.84677781455005, -0.741084525734145), `CD8_C07-LAYN` = c(-4.85420539962432, 
    -3.79535857695107, -2.07599716553024, -2.41001692585172, 
    -3.66993376805675, -1.90910214659534), `CD8_C08-SLC4A10` = c(1.79563839118781, 
    0.431971358693421, 0.24665792844753, 0.820564247625701, -0.941462395796914, 
    0.224912511574641)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `CD8_C03-CX3CR1` = structure(list(...1 = c("5341", "1524", 
    "83888", "2214", "343413", "10219"), ...2 = c("PLEK", "CX3CR1", 
    "FGFBP2", "FCGR3A", "FCRL6", "KLRG1"), ...3 = c(372.816216710618, 
    713.554708746553, 575.834099328186, 419.996034284325, 215.715234731706, 
    281.827177706662), `P-value*` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "3.5450627744914998E-266", 
    "0"), `CD8_C01-LEF1` = c(-1.34745098111019, -0.39476162886016, 
    -0.248194028712413, -0.326944139043036, -0.833877751680806, 
    -0.822668603983214), `CD8_C02-GPR183` = c(0.50737446056126, 
    -0.495638146054913, -0.484905896571723, -0.125753818325312, 
    0.0263098770399738, 0.894340812937189), `CD8_C03-CX3CR1` = c(6.36825282208761, 
    5.38301238794739, 5.26196506464758, 5.6197563760267, 5.8532850807879, 
    5.36851683724817), `CD8_C04-GZMK` = c(1.44463895049283, -0.513803138075432, 
    -0.125340966094923, 0.2447981258131, 1.34537977512099, 2.10784813093189
    ), `CD8_C05-CD6` = c(-0.718776566594413, -0.795121492384525, 
    -0.681892196238474, -0.421395883952147, 0.0987360993173341, 
    -1.35585804120358), `CD8_C06-CD160` = c(-0.550964233191398, 
    -0.794078725052049, -0.707741972359531, -0.156207202527366, 
    2.24842830259497, -1.28977809817504), `CD8_C07-LAYN` = c(0.0641870785667258, 
    -0.785201010640904, -0.631939964779986, -0.340799120353511, 
    0.271892089522186, 0.236064375692484), `CD8_C08-SLC4A10` = c(1.40102283829925, 
    -0.158585496249154, -0.056110756095033, 0.00915832466806331, 
    -0.085141865592199, 3.78847417230501)), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a `purrr` and `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map2(df_list, names(df_list), 
     \(dat, name) {
       dat |>
         select(one = ...1, 
                two = ...2, 
                three = ...3, 
                all_of(name)) |>
         (\(d) filter(d, d[,4] > 3))() |>
         pull(two)
         }
       )
#> $`CD8_C01-LEF1`
#> [1] "CCR7" "LEF1" "SELL"
#> 
#> $`CD8_C02-GPR183`
#> [1] "IL7R"  "S1PR1" "SORL1"
#> 
#> $`CD8_C03-CX3CR1`
#> [1] "PLEK"   "CX3CR1" "FGFBP2" "FCGR3A" "FCRL6"  "KLRG1"
```

EDIT: explaination

`map2` = Here I use this because you have a list of dataframes and `map` works well with lists. I use the "2" variant because you also want to select the column based on the name of the list.

`\(dat, name)` = create an anonymous function with the two inputs from `map2`, where I define the data as `dat` and the name of the list as `name`.

`select(one = ...1,  two = ...2,  three = ...3, all_of(name))` = here I select and rename the first three columns as per your request in the question, and I also select the column that is the name of the list with `all_of(name)`. Remember that `name` is the defined variable name in the anonymous function for the name of the list.

`(\(d) filter(d, d[,4] > 3))()` = This is a little funky syntax because I like to use the native pipe operator (`|>`) rather than the `magritr` pipe operator (`%>%`). what this means is that I create another anonymous function (`\(d)`) that defines the current data as `d`. Then I `filter` `d` based on the 4th column being greater than 3 (i.e.,  `d[,4] > 3`). If you use the `magritr` pipe, this can be simplified to `filter(.[,4] > 3)`. Even better would be to use non-standard evaluation to avoid using the anonymous function at all, but I have trouble figuring out the proper use of `{{}}`, `quo`, `enquo`, and `!!` whith quoted column names.

`pull(two)` = lastly, we select only the values from the column called `two`.

EDIT 2: clean up code.

I figured out the non standard eval to clean up the weird syntax.

```r
map2(df_list, names(df_list), 
     \(dat, name) {
       dat |>
         select(one = ...1, 
                two = ...2, 
                three = ...3, 
                all_of(name)) |>
         filter(!!sym(all_of(name)) > 3) |>
         pull(two)
         }
       )
#> $`CD8_C01-LEF1`
#> [1] "CCR7" "LEF1" "SELL"
#> 
#> $`CD8_C02-GPR183`
#> [1] "IL7R"  "S1PR1" "SORL1"
#> 
#> $`CD8_C03-CX3CR1`
#> [1] "PLEK"   "CX3CR1" "FGFBP2" "FCGR3A" "FCRL6"  "KLRG1"
```

Comment: Nice work! Would you mind commenting on each line so I can educate myself. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I'll update now.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be:

```
res <- lapply(setNames(nm = names(df)), function(dfname) {
  dff <- df[[dfname]]

  # only renaming column 2 as columns 1 and 3 are not used later on
  colnames(dff)[2] <- "two" 

  # not 'keeping' the column with the same name as the dataframe, just using the dataframe straightaway   
  dff$two[dff[,dfname] > 3]
})
```

Note the `setNames(...)` statement as first argument to `lapply`. If you send a named list to `lapply`, it uses the names of the elements as the names of the elements it returns.

Comment: fair points! Very nice and thank you